# Freezes window created with wxPython, if use pyHook

Tags: python, wxpython, pyhook

This code works fine, however when I press minimize or close button, program window freezes on some time. The reason may be in the HookMouse, without it, window minimize and close fine. Why?

```
import wx
import pyHook

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'My Frame')
        self.tc=wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
        wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL|wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.hm = pyHook.HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.OnKeyboardEvent

        self.hm.HookKeyboard()
        self.hm.MouseLeftDown=self.OnKeyboardEvent
        self.hm.HookMouse()

        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.OnClose)

    def OnGetAO(self, event):
        self.tc.Value+=event.MessageName+"\n"

    def OnKeyboardEvent(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.OnGetAO, event)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        del self.hm
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = myFrame()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I think a better question is what are you doing? Why are you hooking into the keyboard and mouse?

Comment: I need global events by keyboard and mouse, that actually undestand?

Comment: Not, my program is working in background and listen global events, as example if user selected text in no matter which program, my app respectively, react to an event.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve your problem:

```
def OnClose(self, event):
    self.hm.UnhookMouse()
    event.Skip()
```

I don't know why because the [doc](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/doc/pyhook/public/pyHook.HookManager.HookManager-class.html) says the destructor unhooks all registered hooks, too.